# Vagrant with docker provisioning

Tags: vagrant, docker, vagrantfile

I am new to docker and vagrant. I installed vmbox and vagrant in my ubuntu 14.04 machine.
I did "git clone https://github.com/dotcloud/docker.git" to get the docker repository. I have also added precise64 from vagrant successfully.

From docker directory i tried "vagrant up". But it told me to do "vagrant init" first. So I did "vagrant init precise64". After doing "vagrant ssh" there is no docker inside the precise64 vm. How can I make sure that docker is installed already in precise64 on startup?

PS: vagrantfile is not allowing " ***config.vm.provision "docker"*** "

Comment: why are you fetching the docker source code with `git clone https://github.com/dotcloud/docker.git`? Are you willing to contribute to the Docker code? If you just intent to use Docker, follow the [installation instructions](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/) or just run `curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ubuntu/ | sudo sh`

Comment: It is given in their doc only http://docker.readthedocs.org/en/v0.5.3/installation/vagrant/

Comment: You might be using old version of vagrant. config.vm.provision "docker" work only with vagrant 1.6.5 . Try upgrading your vagrant

Comment: I would advise against following a outdated documentation. Current Docker version is v1.3.0, your doc is for Docker v0.5.3 which was released over a year ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading the Vagrant to 1.6.5 resolves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The following Vagrantfile will get you a VM with docker ready to go:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "phusion/ubuntu-14.04-amd64"
  config.vm.hostname = "dockerhost"

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SCRIPT
    curl -sL https://get.docker.io/ | sh
    curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotcloud/docker/master/contrib/completion/bash/docker > /etc/bash_completion.d/docker
    adduser vagrant docker
  SCRIPT

end
```

---

### EDIT :

Even easier, you can now use [Docker Toolbox](https://www.docker.com/docker-toolbox) to get up and running.

Comment: can this be updated to use a specific version of docker (older than latest)

Comment: take a look at https://forums.docker.com/t/how-can-i-install-a-specific-version-of-the-docker-engine/1993 and https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/binaries/

Answer (score 1):

You might be using old version of vagrant.

config.vm.provision "docker" work only with vagrant 1.6.5 .

Try upgrading your vagrant to 1.6.5. It will resolve the issue.